# Limitation of description of product variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

One of my client has a WordPress site where each product has variations. The description of each variation is written in the short description field. So far, there were no problems with the site, until the client started adding more variations to a product. There are currently 80-100 variations of a the product. If there are too many variations, the short description, which until now was formatted HTML, turns into plain text and the HTML tags disappear.

I don't know exactly what the problem is. I also tried to increase the number of variations that can be added to the product, but it didn't solve it. It seems that the site has reached some kind of limitation that should be increased.

Wordpress should not remove the HTML tags.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: I suppose it's Woocommerce site. Woocommerce has limit 50 variantions. You can see [here](https://tishonator.com/blog/how-to-increase-woocommerce-variations-count-limit) how to increase.

Comment: I've already tried to increase the number of varioations but it does not work.